# PHP image resizing for different mime types

Tags: php, image, resize

I'm a php noob and trying to create a image resizing script that will shrink uploaded images into smaller dimensions. With my current script below I get the original image displayed. The new width and height aren't registering it seems. Any help is appreciated.

```
    <?php

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
      if (isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
        if ($_FILES['image']['error']==0){
        $new_dir = '/PHP_MySQL_Practice/uploaded/images';
        $fullpath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$new_dir;
        if(!is_dir($fullpath)) {
            mkdir($fullpath, 0777, TRUE); 
        }
        //get file name and type(extension)
        $name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $type = $_FILES['image']['type'];

        //separate image name after first "dot"
        $separated = explode(".", $name);
        //get string before the dot which was stored as the 1st item in the separated array.
        $first = $separated[0];
        //use php function pathinfo to get extension of image file
        $ext = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        //concatenate current timestamp (to avoid file overwrites) with the extracted file 'firstname' and add the extension
        $name = time().'_'.$first.'.'.$ext;
        $target = $fullpath.'/'.$name;

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {

            resizeImage($target, $name);
            echo '<img src="' . $target . '"/>';

        }

    }
    else {

        echo 'there was an error in saving ur image file.';
    }
}   
else {

    echo 'ur image could not be uploaded.';
}
    }
    else {
    ?>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>upload image: </label>
    <input type="file" name="image" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form> 
    <?php   
    }

    //function to resize image
    function resizeImage($dir, $img) {
list($src_w, $src_h) = getimagesize($dir);
$max_w = 150;
$max_h = 150;
if ($src_w > $max_w) {
    $ratio = $max_w / $src_w;
    $new_img_w = $src_w * $ratio;
}
else if ($src_h > $max_h) {
    $ratio = $max_h / $src_h;
    $new_img_h = $src_h * $ratio;
}
$img_mime_type = getimagesize($dir);
switch ($img_mime_type['mime']) {
    case 'image/jpeg':
    case 'image/pjpeg':
        $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($dir);
        return $src;
        break;
    case 'image/gif':
        $src = imagecreatefromgif($dir);
        return $src;
        break;
    case 'image/png':
        $src = imagecreatefrompng($dir);
        return $src;
        break;
    default:
        return FALSE;
        break;
}
$new_img = imagecreatetruecolor($new_img_w, $new_img_h);
imagecopyresampled($new_img, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_img_w, $new_img_h, $max_w, $max_h);
switch ($img_mime_type['mime']) {
    case 'image/jpeg':
    case 'image/pjpeg':
        imagejpeg($new_img, $dir, 100);
        break;
    case 'image/gif':
        imagegif($new_img, $dir);
        break;
    case 'image/png':
        imagepng($new_img, $dir);
        break;
    default:
        return FALSE;
        break;
}

imagedestroy($src);
imagedestroy($new_img);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: take a look on the given tut, hope this will help you that you want http://blog.webtech11.com/2012/04/21/upload-and-resize-an-image-with-php.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some flaws there

1. `imagegif` has only 2 parameters `$im` and save location
2. `imagepng` has compression level from 0 to 9 and not 100
3. you are not saving the images, `null` from `imagejpeg($new_img, null, 100);` should be changed with `$dir`
4. your last functions are `imagdestroy($src);` that is wrong, it should be `imagedestroy($src);`

Your `switch` should be:

```
switch ($img_mime_type['mime']) {
    case 'image/jpeg':
    case 'image/pjpeg':
        imagejpeg($new_img, $dir, 100);
        break;
    case 'image/gif':
        imagegif($new_img, $dir);
        break;
    case 'image/png':
        imagepng($new_img, $dir);
        break;
    default:
        return FALSE;
        break;
}
```

your resize function:

```
function resizeImage($dir, $img) {
    //echo $dir; die;
    list($src_w, $src_h) = getimagesize($dir);
    $max_w = 150;
    $max_h = 150;
    if ($src_w > $max_w) {
        $ratio = $max_w / $src_w;
        $max_w = $src_w * $ratio;
    }
    else if ($src_h > $max_h) {
        $ratio = $max_h / $src_h;
        $max_h = $src_h * $ratio;
    }
    $img_mime_type = getimagesize($dir);
    $src = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($dir));
    $new_img = imagecreatetruecolor($max_w, $max_h);
    imagecopyresampled($new_img, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $max_w, $max_h, $src_w, $src_h);
    switch ($img_mime_type['mime']) {
        case 'image/jpeg':
        case 'image/pjpeg':
            imagejpeg($new_img, $dir, 100);
            break;
        case 'image/gif':
            imagegif($new_img, $dir);
            break;
        case 'image/png':
            imagepng($new_img, $dir);
            break;
        default:
            return FALSE;
            break;
    }

    imagedestroy($src);
    imagedestroy($new_img);
}
```

Comment: The whole switch statement could be replaced with `imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($dir))` and a check for false in case it's an unsupported type.

Comment: modified answer, look at function

Comment: Help for me. It works fine. but it creates png ang gif images with black background. how to set a transparent background.

Comment: @WhiteMarcus just use `imagealphablending($new_img, true);` and `imagesavealpha( $new_img, true );` before `imagecopyresampled`

Comment: @MihaiIorga i done it well, now i have an issue. just now i posted in the question arena. try to help me mate.....

Answer (score 0):

You are not saving the image but rather outputting the contents of your image. If you check the documentation of imagejpeg you will see that the second argument is the path where you want to save your image. So change your second argument (null) to wherever you want to save your resized image.

Answer (score 0):

Use below function to resize image

```
function image_resize($image, $maxWidth, $maxHeight = null)
{
        $file = $image;
        $file_headers = @get_headers($file);

        //validate file not exists
        if( isset($file_headers[0]) && strpos($file_headers[0], '404') ) {
            return;
        }

    $arrayUploadPath = wp_upload_dir();
    $fileUploadSubDir = str_replace(basename($image),'', str_replace($arrayUploadPath['baseurl'], '', $image));
    $fileUploadDir = $arrayUploadPath['basedir'] . $fileUploadSubDir;

    //validate sour ce file existance
    if(!file_exists($fileUploadDir . basename($src))) return null;

    $fileUploadUrl = $arrayUploadPath['baseurl'] . $fileUploadSubDir;
    $srcFileName = $fileUploadDir . basename($image);
    $srcSize = getimagesize($srcFileName);
    $width = $srcSize[0];
    $height = $srcSize[1];

    if( empty($maxHeight) ) {
        $size = wp_constrain_dimensions($width, $height, $maxWidth);
        $maxHeight = $size[1];
    }

    //fix for image_resize_dimensions() constraint in image_resize() function
    if($maxHeight >= $height) $maxHeight = $height - 1;

    $newImage = image_resize($srcFileName, $maxWidth, $maxHeight);

    $newFileNameUrl = !empty($newImage) && !is_object($newImage) ? $fileUploadUrl . basename($newImage) : null;

    return $newFileNameUrl;
}
```

Comment: I'm sure that works and may be more optimal but I'm trying to learn php and therefor trying to work with what I know so far. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this function...

Into this function you can pass height and width as per your requirement because there are total three possibilities in which you can resize image in proportion

1. In case, Height is more than width then you have to resize with height.
2. In case, width is more than width then you have to resize with width.
3. resize with both height and width.

here is example,

```
//first of all get Height and width of image 

 function getHeight($image) {
    $sizes = getimagesize($image);
    $height = $sizes[1];
    return $height;
}

//You do not need to alter these functions
function getWidth($image) {
    $sizes = getimagesize($image);
    $width = $sizes[0];
    return $width;
}
```

now resize with desired dimension here I am working with 500px (height and width both)

```
    $width = $this->getWidth($fullpath);
    $height = $this->getHeight($fullpath);

     $profilecroppedthumb = UPLOAD_PATH."FILENAME_WITH_EXTENSION";
     $fullpath = $uploadDirectory.$filename.'.'.$ext;

        if ($width >= 500 && $height >= 500) {
            thumb($fullpath, $profilecroppedthumb, "500", "500");
        }
        elseif($width >= 500 && $height <= 500)
        {
            thumb($fullpath, $profilecroppedthumb, "500", "");
        } 
        elseif($width <= 500 && $height >= 500)
        {
            thumb($fullpath, $profilecroppedthumb, "", "500");
        }
        else
        {
            $target = fopen($profilecroppedthumb, "w");
            fseek($temp, 0, SEEK_SET);
            stream_copy_to_stream($temp, $target);
            fclose($target);
        } 
 function thumb($file, $save, $width="", $height="")
{   
    //GD-Lib > 2.0 only!
    //@unlink($save);

    //get sizes else stop

    if (!$infos = @getimagesize($file)) {
    //echo $infos = @getimagesize($file); exit('saf');
        return false;
    }

    // keep proportions
    $iWidth = $infos[0];
    $iHeight = $infos[1];
    $iRatioW = $width / $iWidth;
    $iRatioH = $height / $iHeight;


    if($height == "" ) {
        if ($iRatioW < $iRatioH) {
                $iNewW = $iWidth * $iRatioW;
                $iNewH = $iHeight * $iRatioW;
            } else {
                $iNewW = $iWidth * $iRatioW;
                $iNewH = $iHeight * $iRatioW;
            }
    }
    elseif ($width == "")
    {
    if ($iRatioW < $iRatioH) {
                $iNewW = $iWidth * $iRatioH;
                $iNewH = $iHeight * $iRatioH;
            } else {
                $iNewW = $iWidth * $iRatioH;
                $iNewH = $iHeight * $iRatioH;
            }
    }
    else 
    {
        if ($iRatioW < $iRatioH) {
            $iNewW = $iWidth * $iRatioW;
            $iNewH = $iHeight * $iRatioW;
        } else {

            $iNewW = $iWidth * $iRatioH;
            $iNewH = $iHeight * $iRatioH;


        }
    }
    //$iNewW = $width;
    //$iNewH = $height;

    //Don't resize images which are smaller than thumbs
    if ($infos[0] < $width && $infos[1] < $height) {
        $iNewW = $infos[0];
        $iNewH = $infos[1];
    }

    if($infos[2] == 1) {
        /*
        * Image is typ gif
        */
        $imgA = imagecreatefromgif($file);
        $imgB = imagecreate($iNewW,$iNewH);

        //keep gif transparent color if possible
        if(function_exists('imagecolorsforindex') && function_exists('imagecolortransparent')) {
            $transcolorindex = imagecolortransparent($imgA);
                //transparent color exists
                if($transcolorindex >= 0 ) {
                    $transcolor = imagecolorsforindex($imgA, $transcolorindex);
                    $transcolorindex = imagecolorallocate($imgB, $transcolor['red'], $transcolor['green'], $transcolor['blue']);
                    imagefill($imgB, 0, 0, $transcolorindex);
                    imagecolortransparent($imgB, $transcolorindex);
                //fill white
                } else {
                    $whitecolorindex = @imagecolorallocate($imgB, 255, 255, 255);
                    imagefill($imgB, 0, 0, $whitecolorindex);
                }
        //fill white
        } else {
            $whitecolorindex = imagecolorallocate($imgB, 255, 255, 255);
            imagefill($imgB, 0, 0, $whitecolorindex);
        }
        imagecopyresampled($imgB, $imgA, 0, 0, 0, 0, $iNewW, $iNewH, $infos[0], $infos[1]);
        imagegif($imgB, $save);        

    } elseif($infos[2] == 2) {
        /*
        * Image is typ jpg

        */
        $imgA = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
        $imgB = imagecreatetruecolor($iNewW,$iNewH);
        imagecopyresampled($imgB, $imgA, 0, 0, 0, 0, $iNewW, $iNewH, $infos[0], $infos[1]);
        imagejpeg($imgB, $save,100);

    } elseif($infos[2] == 3) {
        /*
        * Image is typ png
        */
        $imgA = imagecreatefrompng($file);
        $imgB = imagecreatetruecolor($iNewW, $iNewH);
        imagealphablending($imgB, false);
        imagecopyresampled($imgB, $imgA, 0, 0, 0, 0, $iNewW, $iNewH, $infos[0], $infos[1]);
        imagesavealpha($imgB, true);
        imagepng($imgB, $save,100);
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Hope this help...